TypeScript discriminated union not narrowing boolean Result type consistently
I have code with a discriminated union over a boolean, an ok field.
In module a, everything works per expectation:
type Result<T, E> = {
    ok: true;
    value: T;
} | {
    ok: false;
    value: E;
};

declare var x: Result<number, string>

if (x.ok) {
  x.ok // true
  x.value // number
} else {
  x.ok // false
  x.value // string
}

But when module b uses that exact same type:
a.getResult({}).then(x => { // x: Result<number, string>
  if (x.ok) {
    x.ok // true
    x.value // number 
  } else {
    x.ok // boolean :(, not false
  }
})

It's very confusing to me why the same type behaves differently across a module boundary. Why would the else block in the second example not be false?

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing, or barring that, a link to an appropriately-configured web IDE that shows it.  Right now I can't reproduce this and I also can't imagine why you'd be seeing such behavior.
